# C# Copying and pasting code with related formatting details

Tags: c#, wpf

Looking for away to copy and paste my code form Visual studio to a word document with code formatting e.g. different colours for key words etc.

Is there also a way to directly output your selected code into a pdf file?

Comment: This is already supported - the text formatting is kept on copy-paste from Visual Studio to MS Word.

Comment: @dymanoid are you sure? Any attempt I have made the colour of the text has been lost?

Comment: Maybe it is version dependent. I use Visual Studio 2017 and MS Word 2016 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using pspad program. Export it to the .rtf then open in MS Word and save as .pdf.

It will stay colored.

**UPDATE**

But when I tried it now, it will stay colored, but. public void for example is black bold (I would say) instead of blue. I think you can work around that.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution to my own problem.

1)Use notepad++, copy and paste code from VS, select the coding language you are using from "Language"

2)then highlight all the code you want to copy with formatting in notepad++

3)Plugins -> Nppexport -> copy RTF to clipboard

then paste code where ever you want, should paste with formatting